# mysql products in category select

Tags: mysql, categories, product

I have a table named product_cats, the relevant columns are

```
product_id,
cat_id
```

Say we have categories 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

I need all the product_id's in cat_id 1 and 2 and (3 or 4 or 5).

I have a few working methods at this point, but they're all terribly slow.

Can someone shed some mysql magic on me?

Edit:

So the product needs to be in both category 1 and 2, and in either 3, 4, or 5.

Here's one of my attempts to get the idea better

```
SELECT
  p1.product_id
FROM
  product_cats p1 JOIN product_cats p2 ON ( p2.product_id = p1.product_id )  
  JOIN product_cats p3 ON ( p3.product_id = p1.product_id )  
  JOIN product_cats p4 ON ( p4.product_id = p1.product_id )   
WHERE
  (p1.category_id=? AND p2.category_id=? AND p3.category_id=?)
  OR 
  (p1.category_id=? AND p2.category_id=? AND p4.category_id=?)
```

Comment: you want products that are both in cat_id 1 and 2? can you show the queries you're trying and making the question clearer? there's no mysql magic... but you can use an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mysql you can implement your logic by using `group by` and `sum` function with `having` clause

```
select product_id
from product_cats
group by product_id
having sum(cat_id = 1) > 0
and sum(cat_id = 2) > 0
and sum(cat_id in(3,4,5)) > 0
```

Above query will return product_ids which has cat_id 1 and cat_id 2 and cat_id can be 3,4,5

Comment: This is perfect. Took my query from 89 seconds to less than 1. Very curious what's actually going on with it though (other than magic), can you explain?

Comment: @user3663448 Its a an aggregation (group by & sum) sum function with some condition in it sum(1=1) will return result as boolean 0 or 1 and grouping by product id it will check for provided criteria like (cat_id = 1) is true or not and same for other conditions and after that i have put this logic to filter out results which doesn't matches this criteria using having clause(commonly used to filter out result of aggregate function) ,hope it make some sense

Answer (score 2):

To select the products that are both in category 1 and 2 you can use a query like this:

```
select
  product_id
from
 product_cats
where
  cat_id in (1,2)
group by
  product_id
having
  count(distinct cat_id)=2;
```

an index on both `product_id` and `cat_id` should help improve performances:

```
alter table product_cats add index idx_product_cats (product_id, cat_id);
```